# Calling Soap webservice from android

Tags: java, android, web-services, soap

I am using the below process,

1)Create a String template for a SOAP request and substitute user-supplied values at     runtime in this template to create a valid request.
   2) Wrap this string in a StringEntity and set its content type as text/xml
   3) Set this entity in the SOAP request.

and with the help of httppost I am posting the request,

I am using a demo webservice from w3schools.com

url--->

http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx

What I have tried is,

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx");          
        StringEntity se;
        try {
            SOAPRequestXML="<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:tem=\"http://tempuri.org/\"><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><tem:CelsiusToFahrenheit><!--Optional:--><tem:Celsius>30</tem:Celsius></tem:CelsiusToFahrenheit></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>";
            Log.d("request is ", SOAPRequestXML+"!!!");
            se = new StringEntity(SOAPRequestXML,HTTP.UTF_8);


        se.setContentType("text/xml");  
        httppost.setHeader("Content-Type","application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8");
        httppost.setEntity(se);  

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        BasicHttpResponse httpResponse = 
            (BasicHttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity resEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        t.setText(EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));



        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I am able to get the response in soapui, so surely the code is wrong because in emulator I am getting the output,

"the server cannot service the request because the media type is unsupported".

Am I passing the correct parameter in the constructor of HttpPost or am I making the correct xml request.I tried a lot but could not figure it out.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a hunch that the emulator android version and the phone version are different.

But I have few suggestions. Use following:

```
httppost.setHeader("Accept-Charset","utf-8");
httppost.setHeader("Accept","text/xml,application/text+xml,application/soap+xml");
```

similarly, set content type as all of the above.

Answer (score 4):

The only problem with your code is you are setting Header as,

```
httppost.setHeader("Content-Type","application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8");
```

instead of,

```
httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml;charset=UTF-8");
```

As you can see the request in the URL that is -> [w3schoools](http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?op=CelsiusToFahrenheit), they are using,

```
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
```

and you where not passing the same content type. So, it was giving you error as,

**The server cannot service the request because the media type is unsupported.**

So, just change the Header and you will get the desired response.

Comment: Is the input xml correct, because I am using soap ui to generate the xml, and the input xml is same as the one generated in soapui.is this the correct way?

Answer (score 3):

I have written an article on How to [Call Web Service in Android Using SOAP](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/88b6e5/how-to-call-web-service-in-android-using-soap/) at c-sharpcorner.com.

So many person get helped from that article. You can also download it and run. I will help you to understand how to use SOAP for web service.

**Edit**

Take a look at following links. It has complex data handling with ksoap.

- [Complex objects tutorial with sample code](http://seesharpgears.blogspot.in/2010/10/ksoap-android-web-service-tutorial-with.html)
- http://bimbim.in/post/2010/10/08/Android-Calling-Web-Service-with-complex-types.aspx
- http://seesharpgears.blogspot.in/2010/10/web-service-that-returns-array-of.html

Comment: i used your method i.e ksoap2 and that worked fine(good article) to get the result from this w3schools web service.But I dont want that because the services which i will be using will contain very complex input and output xml.I wonder ksoap2 will be able to help me in that respect.Please confirm.

Comment: Why not. It will help you to bind your complex data and send it over internet. You can use that for your complex service.

Comment: Hey, I will be using the webservices made in java not .net.Is that fine?

Comment: only web service is important, in which platform it is developed will doesn't matter. Yes, it is right that java web service is bit complex then PHP and .net. But its fine to develop it in java. Go ahead.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the ksoap2 library for Android ?

you can find it here, give it a shot :

https://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/

Hope this helps !

Comment: I am able to get the response using ksoap2, but I dont want that, I just want a response and then I can parse it.

Answer (score 1):

This way the html form is posting 123 celsius. No SOAP or envelops, just working:)

```
    try {
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx/CelsiusToFahrenheit");
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity("Celsius=123");
        httppost.setEntity(se);
        httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        HttpResponse httpResponse = new DefaultHttpClient().execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity resEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        return EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return e.getMessage();
    }
```